# filter files in Blueimp/ jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp

I am trying to use Blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload my project and I want to test the file extension because I only want to download photos
someone show me where and how I should configure blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload so I can do this

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation you can simply set the options to a regex for the file type like that:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            url: '//localhost/',
            maxFileSize: 5000000,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
            process: [
                {
                    action: 'load',
                    fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
                    maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
                },
                {
                    action: 'resize',
                    maxWidth: 1440,
                    maxHeight: 900
                },
                {
                    action: 'save'
                }
            ]
        });
```

Comment: You have to modify the options in the fileupload method. I updated my answer. What do you try to set?

Comment: Error: cannot call methods on fileupload prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Comment: @strongBAD It worked for me 2 years ago. There might be some changes made meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [add method](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin#how-to-tie-a-file-to-an-element-node-during-the-life-cycle-of-an-upload)

So, here is my code for .gpx files:

```js
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  // your fileupload options 
  add:function(e,data){
      data.files.map(function(i){
        if(i.type!='application/gpx+xml'){
          alert('please upload only .gpx files');
        }else{
          data.submit();
        }
    }),
    process: function(e,data){/* your process actions here */}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can use the method `add` for filter files:

```
var $input = $('#upload_input');
$input.fileupload({
  fileInput: $input,
  url: 'YOU_URL',
  // Other options...

  start: function(e, data) {
    // Before start upload... Please wait...
  },
  add: function(e, data) {
    types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i;
    file = data.files[0]
    if (types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)) {
      data.submit();
    } else {
      // alert('Unfortunately, we don’t support that file type. Try again with a PNG, GIF, JPG');
      return;
    }
  },
  done: function(e, data) {
    // After upload... alert('Done');
  },
  fail: function(e, data) {
    // Error. Please try again later...
  }
});
```